# Npm install error EPERM Operation not permitted

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install, npm-start

So when trying to run the angular4 project today my first error was : `npm install eperm operation not permitted` so I thought to delete my node modules folder and retry.  But running npm install I am running in to this error `npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"`.  I've closed vscode to try and run the install to make sure nothing was locking it.  I've tried npm cache clean but results in errors.[image]

Todays latest struggles :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-
  cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   '@angular/cli@latest' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v8.9.3
4 verbose npm-session 2a0bb102467943cf
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 error cb() never called!
```

Admin Results: 
[image]

Any suggestions?

My package.json looks like this :

```
{
 "name": "gamemanagement",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "license": "MIT",
 "scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
   "start": "ng serve",
   "build": "ng build",
   "test": "ng test",
   "lint": "ng lint",
   "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^5.0.1",
  "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
  "@angular/common": "^5.0.1",
  "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.1",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.1",
  "@angular/core": "^5.0.1",
  "@angular/forms": "^5.0.1",
  "@angular/http": "^5.0.1",
  "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.1",
  "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.1",
  "@angular/router": "^5.0.1",
  "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",          
  "angular2-moment": "^1.7.0",
  "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.4",  
  "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.3",
  "ap-angular2-fullcalendar": "^1.3.5",
  "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "firebase": "4.6.2",
  "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
  "jquery": "^3.2.1",
  "moment": "^2.19.3",
  "ng2-date-picker": "^2.6.2",              
  "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
  "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
  "sweetalert2": "^7.0.9",
  "typescript": "^2.6.1",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
 },
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "^1.5.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"ts-node": "~3.2.0",
"tslint": "~5.7.0",
"typescript": "~2.3.3"
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a `package.lock.json` file in the root

Comment: Run this as administrator

Comment: @Cristophs0n no I did look for a package.lock.json and never found one and I have run this command as admin.  I can from other projects run npm start and have no issues so major head scratcher here

Comment: Try closing all other programs, such as your IDE etc. It looks like another process is locking your files

Comment: @Cristophs0n Narrowing down to permission on the particular machine is now my guess because I can not install anything with npm or even run and complete any npm commands

Comment: I had this same problem. For me, the fix was to uninstall `node` and `npm` completely and reinstall it again. Only do this as your last option and also try executing in some other terminal(as administrator if possible). In your case, another `CMD` may be.

Comment: i just uninstalled and reinstalled.  Seems to have fixed it for my other apps.  But quite obviously the main project i'm working on this didnt work

Comment: had same problem and tried everything given on all forum. then classic solution worked, machine restart and retry :-)

Comment: @TroyBryant have you fixed this issue , please help I am also facing same issue and unable to fix by the below given answers .

Comment: @Rupesh Yes and no about fixing the issue.  It happened on 2 different machines.  My work machine and long story short node and everything else was blocked hence me not being able to work on node projects.  My personal machine after running a npm cache clean --force a restart then for good measures running it again then a latest npm install did fix the issue

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue. After cache clean and updating npm everything is ok. So try to run:

npm cache clean --force

npm install -g npm@latest

Comment: npm cache clean --force is throwing permissions error in the AppData Roaming folder

Answer (score 11):

macOS catalina ,

```
            npm init
```

got error

```
       operation not permitted, uv_cwd
```

step 1:   go to parent folder

```
         cd ../
```

step 2:    go to your project folder again,

```
         cd  your-project-folder
```

That is it. it works.

Comment: I have no idea why this works, but it does! Thanks :)

Comment: it works, but how?

Comment: Run `cd .. && cd -`

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 solutions for this

1. you can run  "**npm cache clean**"
2. you run the command prompt in **admin mode**.

Comment: I literally just did this again in admin mode. Posted pic of error

Answer (score 1):

Try below setps, hope this helps.

- Update Node.js
- npm cache clean command in Command prompt, try as    admin

check node proxy settings if persist remove them with below

```
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

Answer (score 1):

Install by yourself the module that is giving the error.

After spending many hours and trying all the possible suggestions, I found that installing the specific module mentioned by the error globally fixed the issue:

For Example:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'Path\Docume
nts\AngularProjects\my-sample-app333\node_modules.staging@angular\core-a3d1aa4
8\ **bundles\core.umd.js**

I run: **npm install -global @angular/core**

and it fixed it for me! Finally!!

Answer (score 0):

Just try `npm cache clean` quick and simple :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything above but it did not work for me.
I copied all content of package.json and deleted the file. Then, I created a new file and copied all there and I saved it as package.json
That fixed everything

Answer (score 0):

100% sure

Firstly delete the project folder. eg: myapp1

Then run   ->**npm cache clean --force**   command

Retype the command that gives error previously.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue but once I removed **node_modules** folder along with **package-lock.json** from the project and then I re-installed entire thing again with `npm i` it worked for me.
[image: My project folder structure]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in one of my Cordova project on MacOS.
In terminal, at my project's root directory, I switched to super user by running following command:

```
sudo su
```

& then I was able to run `npm install` without any issues.