# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename/delete

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, cordova-plugins

I'm struggling with cordova and npm clis errors. I know this is a very common error: I get this error on daily basis on different project and platform.

I noticed my Ionic1 application, which use crosswalk-webview, works with Android 6 but crash with Android 7 (it seems a known [bug](https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-7214)).
**Those are the steps I tried:**

- I tried to remove and re-add crosswalk-webview:
  `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`
  `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`
  I get an npm error on adding the plugin:
  `npm verb stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename...`
- the build fails:
  `ionic cordova build --release android` with the same error:
  `Error: EPERM: operation..`
- since several plugin are outdated, I thought to remove and re-add the whole platform android
  `cordova platform rm android`
  Almost 1 hour later the command is still stuck so I terminated it.

Now if I try to add android as platform I get an error:
`Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename...`

**I tried** to downgrade npm, I tried the following 5.6.0, 5.5.1, 5.4.2, 5.3.0, 5.0.0, 4.6.0 release.
I reinstalled node, cordova, ionic, I cleared npm cache.
I do not solved. It's clearly an NPM issue, maybe here somewhere knows how to solve..

**At the current state**, if I try:
`cordova platform add android`

I get:
`Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\nodejs\myapp\node_modules\.staging\cordova-android-78ae6d2a\node_modules\cordova-registry-mapper'`
The "funny" part if I simply rerun `cordova platform add android` multiple times I get the error "EPERM: operation not permitted" on different modules.

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename?

Comment: This problem have multiple causes, it looks like I solved changing npm directory using `npm config set prefix`

Comment: Try to open `command prompt` in admin mode

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same problem when developing my ionic app, and trying to install some packages. I tried many times to remove and install packages again but everything was unsuccessful.

This solution worked for me :

1. I deleted the "node_modules" folder, then added "node" to the
   exclusions in my Antivirus settings"
2. I opened the command line as Administrator
3. `npm cache clean --force`
4. `npm install -g npm@latest`
5. `npm install --force`

Then, you can try to remove the android platform, add it again and remove the cordova plugin.

By the way, there are many questions related to npm, eg., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47778492/npm-install-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename).